# Reorder numbered legend titles in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to create a plot where each line corresponds to a different value for a fitting parameter. The plot works fine, however in the legend the values are reordered compared to the data frame, where the 'path' (name of parameter) column is in the desired order. My legend titles are 0.1, 0.01, 0.001, 0.0001, 0.00001 and 0.000001. Here is what I am currently running and the resultant plot. Although 'path' (my parameter) is a number, I am encoding as a character to give a discrete legend.

```
combined_DRT <- ggplot(combined_files, mapping = aes(x = tau, y = Mean, group = path))+
  geom_path(aes(colour = path))+
  scale_colour_manual(values = c("blue3", "blue", "cadetblue3", "coral1", "firebrick1", "firebrick3"))+
  labs(x = bquote(tau*"(s)"),
       y = bquote(gamma*"ln"(tau)*(~Omega~ "cm"^2)),
       colour = "\u03bb")+
  theme_classic(base_size = 20)

combined_DRT
```

[Image of plot with disordered legend](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ooql.png)

How do I reorder them to be in numerical order?

I am happy to attach data if necessary - I can email you the txt file, it is quite large for attaching. The data has the form:

```
Lamda |Gamma|x
0.1   |10|1e-6
0.1|11|5e-6
0.01  |20|1e-6
0.01|23|5e-6
0.001|23|1e-6
0.001 |30|5e-6
0.0001|24|1e-6
0.0001|36|5e-6
0.00001|56|1e-6
0.00001|72|5e-6
```

Comment: The important thing here about your data is what is the `path` variable.  Is it numeric, character, factor?  What you want is to make it a factor, and set the levels to be your labels in the order you want them shown.  You might get someone to show you how to do that if you post a minimal dataset that illustrates the issue -- it doesn't need to be your complete dataset.

Comment: try: `fct_inorder` like so: `library(forcats)..... geom_path(aes(colour = fct_inorder(path)) + ....`

Comment: Instead of encoding as a character convert `path` to a `factor`, e.g. try `color = factor(as.numeric(path))` to first convert to a numeric, then to a factor. For more help please provide [a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) including a snippet of your data best shared via `dput()`.